# HTML Form Upon Submission Opens New Tab, Prefer If It Just Redirected On Current Tab

Tags: php, html, css, forms, squarespace

I've inserted the following form code block into my Squarespace website via GetForm -- but, once the form is submitted, a new tab is opened that redirects to the GetForm 'Thank You' page. Instead of opening another tab, I'd like it to redirect on the current tab to the 'Thank You' page -- or, if possible, simply just have the form itself display a 'Thank you, your submission has been received' with no redirect happening at all. Additionally, once the form is submitted, the information that is input into the form remains, is it possible to have the form 'reset' or clear the inputted information after submission?

I'm a complete novice when it comes to anything coding-related and have pieced together the form's code from various Google Searches as well as the GetForm site -- any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
<div class="form-container">
  <div class="title">Apply Now!</div>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://getform.io/f/061fe877-cd4b-4e98-9f70-f5fb2eeb3716" method="POST" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      
    <div class='form-field'><label class='form-label'>Full Name:</label>
      <div class="form-input-container">
        <input class="form-input" type="text" name="full_name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-field'><label class='form-label'>Email Address:</label>
      <div class="form-input-container">
        <input class="form-input" type="email" name="email" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-field'><label class='form-label'>Upload Resume & Cover Letter:</label>
      <div class="form-input-container">
        <input class="form-input" type="file" name="file" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="form-button" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </form>
</div>

<style>
  .form-container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #005019;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 95%;
  }

  .title {
    font-family: "Celias", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
  }

  .form-label {
    font-family: "Celias", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .form-input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: inherit;
    font-family: "Celias", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #2c3e50;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dce4ec;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-width: 2px;
  }

  .form-button {
    border: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: #7BBF42;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease;
    transition: all .15s ease;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: So what does `https://getform.io/f/061fe877-cd4b-4e98-9f70-f5fb2eeb3716` do?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the URL serves as what GetForm calls an "endpoint": https://docs.getform.io/installations/ 

From my understanding, the information submitted to the form gets sent to that URL. GetForm then receives the information, saves it on my account's database, and then emails me that a form submission has occurred

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by after posting the data to the getform site, there is no redirect page. I think you need to find out how to do the redirect after the form is submitted.

Comment: what's strange is that I input the code into an HTML viewer: https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer and filled out the form, submitted it, and the redirect to the GetForm website works. Could it be a problem on Squarespace's end?

Comment: Yes I checked and I think the discrepancies is from squarespace's end. I realize that getform actually support some cotent management systems but configuration can be customed to get that result. Kindly check if this will be helpful. https://blog.getform.io/how-to-setup-a-contact-form-on-squarespace/

Comment: I copied and pasted the example code that GetForm provides in that link and it seems to work. The only thing is that it opens another tab and the 'Return to Previous Page' does not work as a result of that -- would you mind assisting me with just getting the page to load on the same tab? Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue is with the redirect URL. if you can update the question with the current problem it maybe helpful for me to help you with that.

Comment: I've now updated the question and the code shown -- please let me know if I can provide any additional information that may be helpful, thank you! I really appreciate your help with this

Comment: Is there a setting in the Squarespace asking for a redirect URL? If there is then enter the URL of the page there. I think it should work fine.

Comment: Isn't the HTML code above what is causing the new tab to open though? or am I totally wrong there? I'm only seeing options for a 301 and 302 redirect on Squarespace

Comment: I did use that to send a post and it worked perfectly fine so I am quite sure the redirect URL in Squarespace might be the issue. Kindly check that and if there is any trouble please let me know

Comment: Just checked with a different URL and the pop-up still occurred; but, I did some Googling (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/form-submission-new-window/) and it looks like the target="_blank" part is what is causing the new tab to open. But, if I remove it from the code, I run into the original blank page issue I had before